# How to replace a pattern from a TSV using sed?

Tags: regex, sed

I have a TSV file where the char * is used as null identifier and i want to delete it, the file looks like this:

```
Foo Foo foo FOO
Bar *   *   *
*Bar    Foo*    Foo * Bar   Foo bar
*   *   Bar Foobar
```

if i use `s/(^|    )\*(   |$)/\1\2/g` gives this output:

```
Foo Foo foo FOO
Bar     *   
*Bar    Foo*    Foo * Bar   Foo bar
*   Bar Foobar
```

Matching one yes, and one not, what can i do to replace all of them if they are surrounded by TABS?

The desired output should look like this:

```
Foo Foo foo FOO
Bar         
*Bar    Foo*    Foo * Bar   Foo bar
        Bar Foobar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Granting they're tab separated:

```
sed -r 's@([^\t])[*]@\1__0x2A__@g; s@[*]([^\t\r])@__0x2A__\1@g; s@[*]@@g; s@__0x2A__@*@g' file
```

Shorter:

```
sed -r 's@([^\t])[*]@\1\a@g; s@[*]([^\t\r])@\a\1@g; s@[*]@@g; s@\a@*@g' file
```

Output:

```
Foo     Foo     foo     FOO
Bar
*Bar    Foo*    Foo * Bar       Foo bar
                Bar     Foobar
```

Comment: This one did the work, would you please explain how does it work? what does \a do?

Comment: @EmirHerrera `\a` is just a placeholder for all asterisks that would not be removed. Its hex code is 0x07.

Comment: It first replaces all * that are not to be removed with a symbol like \a (alert symbol / 0x07) (`s@([^\t])[*]@\1\a@g; s@[*]([^\t\r])@\a\1@g;`). Then deletes all other remaining `*` (`s@[*]@@g`). After that it puts back the others (`s@\a@*@g`).

Answer (score 3):

As it is not very clear what are the tabs, let's try with `|` as field separator:

```
$ cat a
Foo|Foo|foo|FOO
Bar|*|*|*
*Bar|Foo*|Foo * Bar|Foo bar
*|*|Bar|Foobar
```

So with `awk` we can do:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i=="*") $i=""}1' a
Foo|Foo|foo|FOO
Bar|||
*Bar|Foo*|Foo * Bar|Foo bar
||Bar|Foobar
```

This loops through all the fields and blanks them (sets them as empty) in case their value is exactly `*`.

Note: for this solution to work with your sample input, just replace the definition of the field separator: from `BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}` to `BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}`.

Comment: Good explanation trough using the `|` as the field separator.

Comment: It's an excellent answer but i was looking for something with regex, just beacause... but i'll keep in mind the use of awk for the next one.

Comment: @Emir Herrera just guessing: what is the point of using an overcomplicated regex over a neat awk? To me learning is about following steps and increase the difficulty. Overcomplicated regex just mean you coming back to [so] every time you have a problem instead of learning by yourself. Cheers...

Comment: Because i have only use AWK with files that have a field separator, and i wanted to find a solution involving pattern matching to be more familiarized with regex and work with files that are not field delimited, wich is very common for me, i usually have to put the field delimiter according to a pattern in a text file.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below perl comman,

```
$ perl -pe 's/(\W|^)\*\t\*/\1/g;s/\t\*$//g' file
Foo Foo foo FOO
Bar         
*Bar    Foo*    Foo * Bar   Foo bar
        Bar Foobar
```

Comment: That one will delete all the "*" and i want the preserve the ones that are surrounded by text or any other thing that are not TABS.

Comment: It replaces `Foo*` with `Foo`, but it was close.

Comment: did you want to remove tab*tab? then try `sed 's/\t\*\t//g' file`